# how to select first N rows from a table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Is there any way to select, for example, first 10 rows of a table in T-SQL (working MSSQL)?
I think I saw something in Oracle defined as rownum meta variable, used in a following way

```
select * from Users where rownum<=10
```

But what about MSSQL?

Comment: It is also worth noticing that if You want to take top 10 results in Oracle, You have to write

select * from (select * from Users order by UserName) where rownum <= 10

Rownum is calculated first, before order by.

Comment: @Lukled The same is true when you use row_number() over () in mssql: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16610654/6910

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
select top(@count) * from users
```

If `@count` is a constant, you can drop the parentheses:

```
select top 42 * from users
```

(the latter works on SQL Server 2000 too, while the former requires at least 2005)

Answer (score 10):

You can use Microsoft's row_number() function to decide which rows to return. That means that you aren't limited to just the top X results, you can take pages.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT row_number() over (order by UserID) AS line_no, * 
      FROM dbo.User) as users
WHERE users.line_no < 10
OR users.line_no BETWEEN 34 and 67
```

You have to nest the original query though, because otherwise you'll get an error message telling you that you can't do what you want to in the way you probably should be able to in an ideal world.

```
Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Users
```

Note that if you don't specify an [`ORDER BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) clause then any 10 rows could be returned, because "first 10 rows" doesn't really mean anything until you tell the database what ordering to use.

Comment: +1 for the `order by` distinction. Order without an `order by` is *never* guaranteed by SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use rowcount, but TOP is probably better and cleaner, hence the upvote for Mehrdad

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10
SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE EmployeeID = 5
ORDER BY OrderDate

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: this is a way of parameterizing top N rows in versions of SQL Server pre-2005

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
declare @topval int

set @topval = 5 (customized value)

SELECT TOP(@topval) * from your_database
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT TOP 10 * FROM **TABLE_NAME** ORDER BY **ORDERED_UNIQUE_COLUMN**
>   DESC

**ORDERED_UNIQUE_COLUMN** could be your incrementing primary key or a timestamp

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this doesn't work in MSSQL, but it does work in MySql.